# Organizing Cucumber Steps

Tags: ruby, cucumber

I am dealing with huge code base where features are grouped by domain in and are kept in separate packages.

> +ServicesDomain 
>     |---+features 
>          |+step_definitions
>
> +SalesDomain 
>     |---+features 
>          |+step_definitions

But there are always some common steps and I could not find a way to keep the common step definitions in some common steps package.

What I would like to know is that, if there is way to keep all the generic steps in some common package and make my domain package depend on generic steps package to leverage the generic steps.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it would be to set up a file called features/support/env.rb and add a 'require' statement to this file to include your common steps each time. For instance, the file could contain:

```
require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), ​'..'​, ​'common'​, ​'common_steps'​)
```

That way your common_steps.rb would be loaded each time.

env.rb is the first file to be run on each Cucumber run.

Have you also heard of the Pickle gem? That might be worth a look as it does something similar by putting common steps into a file called 'pickle_steps.rb'. This comes with handy step definitions for testing models but there would be nothing stopping you editing that file and adding your own.

Hope that is of some help?

Comment: Thanks ! This worked. I also took it to another level, by creating a GenericSteps library and importing the lib from env.rb.

Answer (score 0):

Cucumber has a command line option `-r` that allows you to include specific files. If you run `cucumber --help`, you can get more information about all the command line options. In ruby you can combine this with a config.yml file to setup globally how cucumber is run in the project. However I suspect you are using java, and I don't know if that applies. You could ask on the cucumber mailing list if thats the case.

An alternative would be to place a file in each support directory e.g. `ServicesDomain/features/support` and `SalesDomian/features/support` that just has a require statement that pulls in all the common steps. Cucumber automatically loads all the files in `features/support` (when it is run from `features/..`).